# How to use proxy with Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-apiserver

I'm new with Kubernetes and I'm just starting out. My Kubernetes server is running at: 127.0.0.1:3000 and I want it to run at 0.0.0.0:3000. I tried to use

```
kube proxy --bind-address"0.0.0.0"
```

but I'm getting a

> kube: command not found
> error.

I've also tried to use

```
kubectl proxy --address="0.0.0.0"
```

although it says:

> Starting to serve on [::]:8001

but I'm unable to write any commands after that. Is there any way that enables me to use "0.0.0.0" as my IP address and I'm also able to write commands after binding it to the said IP address? Can i change something in my yaml file or kubeconfig file or add a new file for this purpose that enables me to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Use --port argument to change the port

```
kubectl proxy --address=0.0.0.0 --port=8001
Starting to serve on [::]:8001
```

Open another terminal to run commands against ip:8001

Answer (score 0):

Another mistake would be to issue "kube" Command, as you maybe wanted to use "kubectl".

As @confused genius said above, you have to use.

```
kubectl proxy --address=0.0.0.0 --port=3000
Starting to serve on [::]:3000
```